# 0.17 Specify Wallet with RPC/curl

Tags: wallet, json-rpc

In core 0.17 they allow a user to dynamically specify wallets for things like getbalance. So with bitcoin-cli --wallaet='foo' getbalance

But I can't actually figure out how to do this with JSON RPC/ curl? It doesn't seem to work as a parameter or in the --data portion for curl. Can someone help point to how this gets included with an RPC or curl call? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> with bitcoin-cli --wallaet='foo' getbalance

I think you're referring to the `-rpcwallet` flag.

### Usage

The flag changes the endpoint. Try changing the url of the curl call to:

`<rpc-url>/wallet/<url-encoded-wallet-name>`

Example:

```
curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getbalance", "params": ["*", 6] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/wallet/foo
```